# htaccess url rewrite with search

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

i am trying to create an .htaccess file that will achieve the following

1. create a clean url like this www.mydomain.com/About-Us with page page.php?title=About Us
2. query a database with the parameters passed on the url like this www.mydomain.com/?search=abc and it pulls to page index.php?search=abc

this is my code so far

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^?search=([0-9]*)$ index.php?id=$1 ## e.g www.mydomain.com/?search=try
RewriteRule ^([A-Z]*)$ page.php?name=$1 
## www.mydomain.com/About-Us

##ErrorDocument 404 PageNotavailabale


####Protect the system from machines with worms
RewriteRule (cmd|root)\.exe - [F,E=dontlog:1]

#### To hold and redirect css/images/js files
RewriteRule images/(.+)?$ images/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule css/(.+)?$ css/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule js/(.+)?$ js/$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not using this kind of url for your search engine : `www.domain.com/search/abc` ?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$   index.php?search=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$          index.php?page=$1
```

Then, your access your pages with `www.domain.com/<myPage>`.

And your search engine with `www.domain.com/search/<mySearch>`

EDIT :

Please notice your rules doesn't allow a lot of params :

- `^?search=([0-9]*)$` allows only numbers (even an empty parameter)
- `^([A-Z]*)$` allows only uppercase letters (and also empty parameter)